# Regular expression for matching functions

Tags: c#, expression

I am using the following regular expression (from http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/regular-expression-based-token-replacement-in-asp.net/)

(?<functionName>[^\$]*?)\((?:(?<params>.**?)(?:,|(?=\))))*?)

it works fine, except when I what to include brackets within the parameters such
as "<b>hello<b> renderHTML(""GetData(12)"") "

so I want "GetData(12)" instead I get "GetData(12".

Is there a way to ignore any matches if they are wrapped in double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to ignore the parens inside of quotes but this will not solve your problem.  Function calls in C# cannot be matched with a regular expression .  Regular expressions cannot match nested structures such as they way both parens and `<` appear inside of a function call.  To match these you need to use a grammar of sorts.

I while back I wrote a blog post which goes into a bit more detail about this problem

- [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/15/regular-expression-limitations.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jaredpar/regular-expression-limitations)

I don't mean to be avoiding the answer here.  But any answer to this question will just be broken by a slightly more complex (or sometimes even simpler) function call.

Comment: I have read the post, it does not suggest the possible answers to the problem. Can I ask what would you do for the solution? I do not want anything too complex as there will only be few commands available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Podge, the only really answer is to write a full parser for the language.  Or a hacky one that can properly match `(`'s and '<`'s.